# Loading JavaScript in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first post on SO and my first time making a Chrome Extension.  I've read alot of documentation, but I am still unsure how to get this to work.  Below are my html and js files.  I want to be able to type something in the source box and have the have the word print out in the results area in real time.  I have tested this code on my local host so i know it works, but for some reason it is acting up as a chrome extension.

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Getting Started Extension Popup</title>
<style>
  body {
  min-width: 357px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }

img {
   margin: 5px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 75px;
   height: 75px;
}
</style>

<script src="popup.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<textarea id="source"></textarea>

<div id="result">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the js:

```
 function main() {
  document.getElementById('source').keydown(function() {
    var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
    var outputValue = source.replace(/command/gi, "⌘")
                            .replace(/tab/gi, "⇥")
                            .replace(/return/gi, "⏎")
                            .replace(/option/gi, "⌥")
                            .replace(/control/gi, "⌃")
                            .replace(/esc/gi, "⎋")
                            .replace(/left/gi, "←")
                            .replace(/down/gi, "↓")
                            .replace(/up/gi, "↑")
                            .replace(/right/gi, "→")
                            .replace(/shift/gi, "⇧")
                            .replace(/eject/gi, "⏏")
                            .replace(/caps\s\(lock\)/gi, "⇪")
                            .replace(/save/gi, "⌘ + S")
                            .replace(/print/gi, "⌘ + P")
                            .replace(/find/gi, "⌘ + F");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = outputValue;
 } 
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `element.keydown(function() { ... })` in pure js. Use `element.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { ... });` If by any chance this is your custom extension of the DOM then the code posted in the question isn't enough to diagnose the problem. Also it's not clear what exactly happens. Can you edit the question and add manifest.json? And I think a link to the entire extension zip would be helpful to test it live.

Comment: Thank you sooo sooo much.  I solved the issue.  I thought keydown was a JS thing.  I'm so used to jQuery that's all

Comment: Make use of the devtools [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging), you can solve this kind of issues in seconds by setting breakpoints and/or stepping through the code (F10/F11 keys) and examining the surrounding context (select any expression that can be evaluated in the currently executed function chain and hover the mouse).

Answer (score 2):

1) What wOxxOm said in the comment: `element.keydown(function() { ... })` does not exist. This definitely comes from some jQuery code - you could use that if you add it to your extension, or you could [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

2) You declare a function `main()`, but nothing ever calls it. A good place to call it would be a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener on `document`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);

function main() {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Your and wOxxOm's solutions and explanations were spot on!  Thank you! :)

Comment: @RaquelHosein BTW, there's nothing wrong with using jQuery in extensions - just make sure you include a copy of it, instead of trying to load it from a CDN.